# how to include css file in codeigniter

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

Hi I have a php file in which all the css files are included, how I include that file in my header. here is my php file which i want to include in my header:

```
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link href="css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link href="css/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Hope my answer help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42549892/how-to-include-css-file-in-codeigniter/42550927#42550927

Comment: You have not accepted any answer below.

Answer (score 2):

> ***Note:*** Make sure you have set your base url in config.php it's a must do in codeigniter 3 versions
>
> `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/projectname/';`
>
> Or live  domain something like
>
> `$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/';`

Make sure your css, js, images etc are ***out side of the application folder***. if you have it inside application folder it will get blocked.

```
application 
assets
assets > css > bootstrap.css
assets > js > bootstrap.js
assets > images
system
index.php
```

Autoload the [**url helper**](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) in config/autoload.php

> *Autoloading helpers and libraries etc are good you can autoload the ones you think you will use regularly*

Example loading using [**base_url()**](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#base_url)

In your head area you can place

```
<head>
// Meta
// Title
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.css');?>"/>
<!-- Load jQuery.js file before your bootstrap.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/bootstrap.js');?>"></script> 
<!-- you can place the boostrap js on the body if you want as they say but i place in head. -->
</head>
```

Controller

```
<?php

class Example extends CI_Controller {

  public function index() {
     $this->load->view('header');
     $this->load->view('content');
     $this->load->view('footer');
  }
}
```

I am not sure if this what you after but not sure why you would want to do it.

```
<head>
// Meta
// Title
<?php $this->load->view('css');?>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your file is `application/views/common/css_links.php`

You should add:

```
<head>
    <?=$this->load->view('common/css_links')?>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a file included all css file,so you can do that

```
all.css file content:
@import url(a.css);
@import url(b.css);
@import url(c.css);
```

in head you just include all.css

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<link href="<?=base_url('folder/file.css')?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score -1):

If you keep your all `css` file in `view` folder in codeigniter and your css file name is for example `template` then add the following code where you want to add all css file.

```
 $this->load->view('template');
```

Answer (score -2):

Add like this:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>items/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: why on earth would you do that??